# Find all values of $x$, linear and quadratic functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Use special triangles to give exact solutions where possible. Find all values of $x$ such that $0 \leq x \leq 2 \pi$.

1) $\cos^2 x + \cos x - 1 = 0$
For this question, I have factored in which the quadratic formula was required.  The two answers I got were $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x = -1$. Meaning that the factors should be $(2x - 1)(x + 1)$. Then I need to take $cos x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\cos x = -1$ and try to isolate for $x$. However at around this point I am not sure what to do. I took the first equation $cos x = \frac{1}{2}$ and got it to $x = \cos - 1(\frac{1}{2})$ after which I would need to use the special triangles to determine the value of related acute angle. However I am not certain if this is correct. I got $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$ for that one, and $x = \cos - 1(-1)$ which I am not sure how to determine.

2) $2 \cos^2 x = 1 + \sin x$
For this question, I started by getting everything over to the left side, so $2 \cos^2 x - 1 - \sin x = 0$. However, at this point I am already stuck. I am not sure if there is a trig identity or a Pythagorean identity that will work here.

Comment: Check your factorisation for (1). You should've got $\cos x = \dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt5}2$.

Comment: Really? Because I had someone else check that before and they told me that what I had done was correct

Comment: @Aria Check your factorization. It seems that Macavity has gotten the right one. Are you sure your equation isn't $2\cos^2(x) + \cos(x) - 1 =0$?

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$

$\cos^2x+\cos x=1\iff(2\cos x+1)^2=5$

Now $-1\le\cos x\le1\iff-1\le2\cos x+1\le1\implies(\cos x+1)^2\le1<5$

$(2)$

Use $\cos^2x-1-\sin^2x$

Now $\cos x=\cos A\implies x=2m\pi\pm A$ where $m$ is any integer

Find the suitable values of $m,n$ such that $0\le x\le2\pi$

OR

$$\sin x=2\cos^2x-1=\cos2x$$

$$\cos2x=\sin x=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)$$

$$\cos2x=\cos\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)$$

use $(1)$

Comment: That doesn't look very similar to how we've been learning how to do it in class.

Comment: @Aria, Please find the edited version

Comment: That is the version I am looking at.